# What does the C++ output of the HipHop PHP compiler look like?

Tags: php, performance, programming-languages, build, language-design

Is it clean enough that you can discard the PHP and hand-optimize the C++ code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: **no**.

Since I spent some time to get HipHop to work, I decided to share my results here so I don't feel like a COMPLETE waste of time.

Here's my PHP input:

```
<?

class test {
 function loop() {
  for($i=0; $i<10; ++$i) {
    echo("i = $i\n");
  }
 }
}

$t = new test();
$t->loop();

?>
```

And here's the C++ output...

```
#include <php/hello.h>
#include <cpp/ext/ext.h>

namespace HPHP {
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/* preface starts */
/* preface finishes */
/* SRC: hello.php line 3 */
Variant c_test::os_get(const char *s, int64 hash) {
  return c_ObjectData::os_get(s, hash);
}
Variant &c_test::os_lval(const char *s, int64 hash) {
  return c_ObjectData::os_lval(s, hash);
}
void c_test::o_get(ArrayElementVec &props) const {
  c_ObjectData::o_get(props);
}
bool c_test::o_exists(CStrRef s, int64 hash) const {
  return c_ObjectData::o_exists(s, hash);
}
Variant c_test::o_get(CStrRef s, int64 hash) {
  return c_ObjectData::o_get(s, hash);
}
Variant c_test::o_set(CStrRef s, int64 hash, CVarRef v,bool forInit /* = false */) {
  return c_ObjectData::o_set(s, hash, v, forInit);
}
Variant &c_test::o_lval(CStrRef s, int64 hash) {
  return c_ObjectData::o_lval(s, hash);
}
Variant c_test::os_constant(const char *s) {
  return c_ObjectData::os_constant(s);
}
IMPLEMENT_CLASS(test)
ObjectData *c_test::cloneImpl() {
  c_test *obj = NEW(c_test)();
  cloneSet(obj);
  return obj;
}
void c_test::cloneSet(c_test *clone) {
  ObjectData::cloneSet(clone);
}
Variant c_test::o_invoke(const char *s, CArrRef params, int64 hash, bool fatal) {
  if (hash < 0) hash = hash_string_i(s);
  switch (hash & 1) {
    case 1:
      HASH_GUARD(0x0EA59CD1566F5709LL, loop) {
        return (t_loop(), null);
      }
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  return c_ObjectData::o_invoke(s, params, hash, fatal);
}
Variant c_test::o_invoke_few_args(const char *s, int64 hash, int count, CVarRef a0, CVarRef a1, CVarRef a2, CVarRef a3, CVarR
ef a4, CVarRef a5) {
  if (hash < 0) hash = hash_string_i(s);
  switch (hash & 1) {
    case 1:
      HASH_GUARD(0x0EA59CD1566F5709LL, loop) {
        return (t_loop(), null);
      }
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  return c_ObjectData::o_invoke_few_args(s, hash, count, a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5);
}
Variant c_test::os_invoke(const char *c, const char *s, CArrRef params, int64 hash, bool fatal) {
  return c_ObjectData::os_invoke(c, s, params, hash, fatal);
}
Variant cw_test$os_get(const char *s) {
  return c_test::os_get(s, -1);
}
Variant &cw_test$os_lval(const char *s) {
  return c_test::os_lval(s, -1);
}
Variant cw_test$os_constant(const char *s) {
  return c_test::os_constant(s);
}
Variant cw_test$os_invoke(const char *c, const char *s, CArrRef params, bool fatal /* = true */) {
  return c_test::os_invoke(c, s, params, -1, fatal);
}
void c_test::init() {
}
/* SRC: hello.php line 4 */
void c_test::t_loop() {
  INSTANCE_METHOD_INJECTION(test, test::loop);
  int64 v_i = 0;

  {
    LOOP_COUNTER(1);
    for ((v_i = 0LL); less(v_i, 10LL); ++v_i) {
      LOOP_COUNTER_CHECK(1);
      {
        echo((LINE(6,concat3("i = ", toString(v_i), "\n"))));
      }
    }
  }
} /* function */
Object co_test(CArrRef params, bool init /* = true */) {
  return Object(p_test(NEW(c_test)())->dynCreate(params, init));
}
Variant pm_php$hello_php(bool incOnce /* = false */, LVariableTable* variables /* = NULL */) {
  FUNCTION_INJECTION(run_init::hello.php);
  {
    DECLARE_GLOBAL_VARIABLES(g);
    bool &alreadyRun = g->run_pm_php$hello_php;
    if (alreadyRun) { if (incOnce) return true;}
    else alreadyRun = true;
    if (!variables) variables = g;
  }
  DECLARE_GLOBAL_VARIABLES(g);
  LVariableTable *gVariables __attribute__((__unused__)) = get_variable_table();
  Variant &v_t __attribute__((__unused__)) = (variables != gVariables) ? variables->get("t") : g->GV(t);

  (v_t = ((Object)(LINE(11,p_test(p_test(NEWOBJ(c_test)())->create())))));
  LINE(12,v_t.o_invoke_few_args("loop", 0x0EA59CD1566F5709LL, 0));
  return true;
} /* function */

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
```

Yuck! It took me several seconds to even find the loop...

Comment: That seem "normal" as there seem to be a lot of code to simulate php features, so most of what you see generated is "binding" code (but that's not the right word). You should not be surprised for such code as it is generated from a totally different paradigms based language. A C++ programmer writing from scratch would have written the same thing with almost the same size of code than your php snippet (using STL).

Comment: That said, +1 : it's definitively not hand-optimizable. It seem already optimized a lot (but to be sure, a look at some macro definitions would be necessary).

Comment: It seems to me the HipHop developers didn't really go out of their way to make the output readable. They COULD have employed inheritance, templates, and macros to reduce the amount of explicit "binding" code.

Comment: How did you get a CPP output? I have tried HHVM but cant bet cpp files from that

Answer (score 0):

***>> "A C++ programmer writing from scratch would have written the same thing with almost the same size of code than your php snippet (using STL)."***

A G-WAN ANSI C scripts programmer writing from scratch would have written the (massively more efficient) code below:

```
static inline void loop(xbuf_t *reply) 
{
  int i = 0; 
  while(i < 10)
    xbuf_xcat(reply, "i = %d\n", i++);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   xbuf_t *reply = get_reply(argv);
   loop(reply);
   return 200;
}
```

The curious will benchmark each implementation. The **really** curious will check memory usage.

Even Lighttpd or Nginx with natively pre-compiled C++ is slower than G-WAN's C scripts.

Food for thoughts...